# cambiar base de datos por cada usuario

Tags: base-de-datos, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Estoy desarrollando un sitio web multiempresarial en el que cada empresa tiene su base de datos y cuando el usuario inicia sesión entonces va a acceder con la base de datos de la empresa a la que esta asociado teniendo cada usuario un registro llamado "empresa.id". El problema viene cuando un usuario de una empresa "X" inicia sesión y luego otro usuario de una empresa "Y" también inicia sesión haciendo que gracias a este ultimo usuario de la empresa "Y" cambie la base de datos para todo el sistema afectando también para el usuario de la empresa "X" y todos los demás usuarios en vez de que cada usuario este haciendo uso de una base de datos en especifica sin ser afectados por la base de datos de los demás usuarios.

Este es mi código para cambiar la base de datos(hago uso de el en applicationController):

```
before_action :set_database

def set_database
   if usuario_signed_in?
      empresa = (current_usuario.empresa_id).to_s.to_sym 
      ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(empresa)
    else
      ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(:'232')
    end
 end
```

La variable "empresa" tomara el valor de "empresa_id" del usuario y hara la conexion con la base de datos de la empresa, por ejemplo "empresa" tiene un valor "32" entonces hara la conexion en database.yml con:

```
'32':
  adapter: sqlserver
  mode: dblib
  dataserver:
  host: host
  port: 1433
  database: database
  username: user
  password: pass
  timeout: 60000
  azure: true
```

Como puedo iniciar sesión con varios usuarios sin afectar otros que tengan una base de datos diferente?

Comment: Estoy con @Macupo, lo que describes es un mal diseño de aplicación, en el que estás intentando solucionar el problema incorrecto. Estás intentando tratar los síntomas en lugar de la causa

Comment: Creo que estás mal enfocado. No creo que valga la pena el esfuerzo de crear múltiples bases de datos para que al importar/exportar solo tengas los datos de dicha empresa. Eso perfectamente lo puedes hacer sin necesidad de múltiples bd, solo estructurando bien tus tablas. De hecho lo que mencionas no es común en una arquitectura multitenant, quizás en una etapa en la que tengas que entrar a escalar la aplicación podrías evaluarlo, pero en esta etapa donde recién estás iniciando tu proyecto, te traerá más dolores de cabeza que alivio.

Answer (score 1):

Buenas

Primeramente, disculpas, se que no es la solución a tu pregunta, aunque tal vez sí a tu problema.

¿Por qué no te planteas usar la misma base de datos para todos los usuarios?

Es decir, al identificar el usuario identificar la empresa del mismo, por ejemplo Nombre: Macupo Empresa: LAM

Entonces, solo tendrías que añadir una columna más a cada tabla para distinguir las empresas. Por ejemplo TAB_CODEMP = LAM.

Creo que simplificaría bastante el desarrollo que pretendes llevar a cabo (a cambio de, en previsión de futuro, tener tablas con más campos para satisfacer los diferentes requisitos).

Saludos

Comment: Gracias por responder, había pensado en esta solución pero como el sistema se manejaría por varias empresas, lo ideal seria tener una base de datos para cada una y así cuando se decida exportar e importar, solo estén los datos de cada empresa.

Answer (score 0):

La gema Apartment se encarga de hacer lo que estás buscando. La arquitectura que querés se llama MultiTenancy.

https://github.com/influitive/apartment

Supongamos que tu aplicación tiene una tabla de productos.
Con apartment vas a poder seleccionar entre los tres tipos de Tenancy posible:

- Usar una única tabla productos con una columna (por ejemplo)
  empresa_id que va a distinguir a qué empresa pertenece el producto.
- Usar una misma base de datos, pero con diferentes Schemas para cada
  empresa.
- Usar una base de datos diferente para cada empresa.

Espero te sirva para que sigas investigando y encuentres lo que estás buscando!

Aquí te dejo un Screencast donde explican como configurar y utilizar Apartment
https://gorails.com/episodes/multitenancy-with-apartment